# absolute convergence of series and ultrafilters

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\mathcal F$ be  a free ultrafilter on $\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,\dots\}$. Does there exist $a\in \ell^2$ such that $a|_F$ is not summable for every $F\in \mathcal F$?